# n-D Trees - calculating the coordinates of hypercubes

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

I am trying to implement a generic n-dimensional Tree that will hold n-dimensional data. By n-dimensional data I mean data points having 6-7 coordinates in my case. Here is the Tree Node (a compound data type) and the Tree Class:

```
#data = data points (i.e. [x,y,z,k,m,n])
#hypercube = set of tuples; coordinates [(x0,x1),(y0,y1)...]
class _Node:
    def __init__(self, data, hypercube):
        self.data = data
        self.hypercube = hypercube

class _nTree:
    def __init__(self, hypercube, depth = 0):
        self.node = []
        self.children = []
        self.depth = depth
        self.hypercube = hypercube

    def __insert__(self, data):
        if not self.node:
            self.node = _Node(data, self.hypercube)
            if (len(self.node.data) != 1):
                self.__split__()
```

In my case, every child will contain data that is contained within its parent node - that's the reason behind checking if the len(self.node.data) is not equal to 1. If we only have 1 data point contained within the hypercube, then we stop and we have a leaf node. If we have multiple ones, we split further. A data point will be placed in a hypercube only if it is is within the boundaries defined by the coordinates of the hypercube.

For example, imagine you have a 2D plane of coordinates [(0,1),(0,1)] - our root node. We want to populate it with the data points [(0.5, 0.1),(0.2,0.3)]. Since we have two data points, we split the plane into 2^n new hypercubes (or squares in this case), where n is the number of dimensions - 2 in this case. From a root square of 1x1 we get 4 smaller square of coordinates [[(0, 0.5), (0, 0.5)], [(0.5, 1), (0.5, 1)], [(0.5, 1),(0, 0.5)], [(0, 0.5),(0.5, 1)] - which would basically be the children of the root node. This is an example of a quad-Tree which can be visualized here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

I am trying to do the same thing, but with multiple dimensions.

Now that I tried to explain what I am trying to do, my question is:

The hypercube variable contains the coordinates of the current node. How can I implement my split function in a way that it will generate the coordinates correctly? For example, if I have 6 dimensions, I have to generate 64 coordinates for every node ( 2^n; n = number of dimensions). As a heads up, it is not a k-D tree.

EDIT: I thought I should post my current **split** function:

```
def __split__(self):
    n_of_children = 2**(len(self.node.hypercube[0]))
    vector = self.__get_vector__() #returns the coordinates of all 64 hypercubes/trees
    self.children = [_nTree(vector, self.depth+1) for i in range(n_of_children)[ 
    self.__insert_children__(self.data)
```

I declare each child as a tree structure and then I call insert_children to decide into which child each data point goes into. If a child has more than one data point in it, we repeat the whole process of splitting and inserting.

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a k-dimensional quadtree in Java, here is the code:

```
NodeKD(double[] min, double[] max, int maxDepth, NodeKD parent) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.center = new double[min.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < min.length; i++) {
        this.center[i] = (max[i]+min[i])/2;
    }
    this.maxDepth = maxDepth == -1 ? 4 : maxDepth;
    this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    qA = new NodeKD[1 << min.length];
    this.parent = parent;
}

private void subdivide() {
    int dim = min.length;
    double[] min = new double[dim];
    double[] max = new double[dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < qA.length; i++) {
        long mask = 1L;
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            if ((j & mask) == 0) {
                min[j] = this.min[j];
                max[j] = this.center[j];
            } else {
                min[j] = this.center[j];
                max[j] = this.max[j];
            }
            mask <<= 1;
        }
        qA[i] = new NodeKD(min, max, maxDepth-1, this);
    }
}
```

However, as far as I can tell, quadtree (2D) and octrees (3D) are not very efficient for higher dimensions. Depending on what you want to do (range queries, nearest-neighbour queries, simple look-up, lots of inserts, ...) I would choose a different structure. KD-Trees are quite simple and okay for insertion/deletion. R-Trees (R+tree, R*tree, X-tree) are quite good for range queries and nearest neighbour queries. However the original R-Tree is quite bad for modifying adding/removing data later.

My personal favorite is my own [PH-Tree](http://www.ph-tree.org). It is similar to a k-dimensional quadtree but with some differences:

- It is essentially a 'trie', or critbit tree. That means it looks at the bit representation of the values an split whenever one value is '0' and another is '1'. Since I operate on bit level, navigation and addressing within a node is very efficient, because I can simply operate on a k-bit string (for k dimensions) to iterate through local children and check their applicability for a query. This avoids many problems with scalability with high dimensionality
- It uses prefix-sharing to reduce memory requirements (each node stores only the bits where the local values differ from each other).
- Due to the static nature (splitting according to bits), no modification will ever affect more than two nodes, there is never rebalancing required.
- While there is no rebalancing, the depth of the tree is limited to 64 (assuming 64 bit values), so it cannot degenerate badly.

Some more details can be found [here](http://globis.ethz.ch/?pubdownload=699) and [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree/blob/master/PhTreeRevisited.pdf). The drawback is that the current [open-source version](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree) is in Java only (not python) and is quite complicated. I have a considerably improved version (much simpler code) on the way, but it may take a while before I can release it.

Comment: In my case, I cannot use a k-D Tree since they are dependent on the data. In my case, all I have to do is insert the data and count the number of nodes that contain data points on a specific level. Thanks for sharing your thoughts! I did read about the data structures that you mentioned before I started building my own but none of them can give me the desired result.

Comment: Well, all tree-like structures 'depend on data', as you put it. There is no real way around it :-). I'm not sure what you mean by 'specific level', do you mean within a certain range of values?

Comment: By level I meant the depth of the tree. When I am done inserting the data I want to count the number of nodes, at a particular depth, that contain data and ignore the ones that do not.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got misunderstood, I wrote a k-dimensional quadtree, not a k-D-tree. So I think the code above is exactly what you where asking for? You just have to set 'dim' to 6 or 7. The loop creates the splitting point so that you get 2^k children per node.

Comment: I apologize. I really thought you wrote a k-D one. I did fix the splitting part and now I am correctly calculating the coordinates. The method I am using is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar implementation that I developed for running cppn queries in a hypercube space. When reviewing the algorithm of an quadtree I also noticed that the subdivision should yeild 2^n coordinates, and also picked up on the fact that this coordinates are represented by a permutation of the sum of the length of the dimension, and (+ or -) that value/2. Since its the value that changes as we permute can only be in two states I found a incredibly elegant solution to finding the permutations of a binary string here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24690/print-all-binary-strings-of-length-n using this you can loop 2^n create a new point and using the bitstring permutation at that index to determine the sign (1 = positive and 0 = negative) of the second number in the sum for that dimensions value.

Below I have included first the java implementation as I think its more readable and the bitstring permutation is more elegant, and below that is a python implementation but does not use int->bitstring to generate the permutations. Both of these will subdivide any dimension n coord into 2^n subtrees

```
public class FractalTree {
    public double[] coord;
    public double width;
    public double weight;
    public double lvl;
    public String[] signs;
    public FractalTree[] children;
    public FractalTree(double[] c, double width, int lvl) {
        this.coord = c;
        this.width = width;
        this.lvl = lvl;
        this.children = new FractalTree[(int)Math.pow(2.0, (double)c.length)];
        this.permute_signs(this.coord.length);
    }
    public void subdivide_into_children() {
        for(int idx = 0; idx < this.children.length; idx++) {
            String sign_pattern = this.signs[idx];
            double[]  new_coord = new double[this.coord.length];
            for(int idx_2 = 0; idx_2 < this.coord.length; idx_2++) {
                char sign = sign_pattern.charAt(idx_2);
                if(sign == '1') {
                    new_coord[idx_2] = coord[idx_2] + this.width/2.0;
                } else {
                    new_coord[idx_2] = coord[idx_2] - this.width/2.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void permute_signs(int coord_len) {
        String str_len = "%" + Integer.toString(coord_len) + "s";
        for(long ix = 0; ix < this.children.length; ix++) {
            this.signs[(int)ix] = String.format(str_len, Long.toBinaryString(ix)).replace(' ', '0');
        }
    }

}

class nDimensionTree:

    def __init__(self, in_coord, width, level):
        self.w = 0.0
        self.coord = in_coord
        self.width = width
        self.lvl = level
        self.num_children = 2**len(self.coord)
        self.cs = [None] * self.num_children
        self.signs = self.set_signs()
        print(self.signs)
    def set_signs(self):
        return list(itertools.product([1,-1], repeat=len(self.coord)))

    def divide_childrens(self):
        for x in range(self.num_children):
            new_coord = []
            for y in range(len(self.coord)):
                new_coord.append(self.coord[y] + (self.width/(2*self.signs[x])))
            newby = nDimensionTree(new_coord, self.width/2, self.lvl+1)
        self.cs.append(newby)
```